# Any way for revisions to show up in a different color from an older saved .fdr to a newer saved .fdr in version 7 of FinalDraft?

Tags: software, screenwriting

Need some help on how to have updated changes show up in a different color scheme for my screenwriting partner. I have the script saved each day under a different date.

Comment: What software are you using?  I don't recognize the .fdr extension or the reference to version 7 -- which, granted, means I probably can't help answer your question, but the more information you include, the easier it will be for others to help you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Final Draft 7, if you run the ScriptCompare tool (`Tools` > `ScriptCompare`) against the previous day's file, it generates a document that shows the changes from that version. You could send the changes file, along with the latest screenplay file, to your writing partner - or your writing partner could generate the changes file him/herself against their previous version of the script.

Alternatively, if you are revising an existing script, you can use the production tools to track changes by locking the script (`Production` > `Lock Pages`) - this locks page numbers and shows changes with asterisks in the margins, which you could eventually 'unlock' again - but for anything more than a few pages worth of revisions, usually during production, this would be quite painful and probably counter-productive.